# How to make Java save my background image in extracted, compiled java program?

Tags: java, imageview, fxml

When I try to run my extracted/compiled java program I can see pictures cause they are stored on my PC and addressed in the code from my PC. But when I try the same program on another PC, pictures/backgrounds are gone.
How to store pictures into java code *while I'm calling them from a dis*k into ImageView so they are viewable on other systems too ?
I am using JavaFX and FXML, CSS.

Comment: Add them to the JAR file, by moving them to the CLASSPATH, and use a `ClassLoader` to open them at run-time...

Comment: Are you saying I should move them to the same package where my classes are ? Second part I understood, runing them in the main class close to the root codes. Sorry, I just started with Java.

Answer (score 0):

You can bundle your images with java program using two ways:

1) put them inside your jar - create a package named eg. "images" and add the images there, then load it using

`BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResourceAsStream("/images/image.jpg"));`

2) put them in to the same folder as your jar and load them with:

`BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new File("image.jpg"));`

For you the best way is probably the #1 because youll get just one jar - it is easier to copy such jar and harder to tamper the images.

Answer (score 0):

I've done it like this. Thanks!

```
@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception
{
    Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("/grafika.fxml"));      
    Scene scene = new Scene(root);  
    scene.getStylesheets().add("/application.css");

    Image picture1 = new Image("/kava.jpg");                                   
    ImageView slika1 = new ImageView(picture1);
    slika1.setImage(picture1);

    stage.setScene(scene);                                                      
    stage.setMaxHeight(530);
    stage.setMaxWidth(800);
    stage.setResizable(false);
    stage.show();
}
```

Comment: Hi, if this represents the right solution to your problem, please consider to mark it as the accepted answer for future reference